# Generated Linear Varieties

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm reading Luenberger's Optimization text, and I'm confused by a definition:

*Let $S$ be a subset of a vector space $X$. The **linear variety generated by $S$**, denoted $v(S)$, is the intersection of all linear varieties in $X$ that contain $S$.* A linear variety is defined as a translation of a subspace.

Can someone give me a couple examples of a linear variety generated by a subset of a vector space? I'm having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: I guess you mean '*subspace*' as 'linear variety'. Or what?

Comment: I'm just quoting straight out of Luenberger. Not quite sure either.

Comment: But it's written: 'A linear variety is defined as a *translation* of a subspace'. If 'translation' is not used in the meaning, like from one language to another, then it probably means *shift* by some vector $v$, i.e. the map $x\mapsto x+v$, and then '*linear variety*' means **affine subspace** in modern terminology. More context could help to clarify it.

Comment: A footnote in Luenberger states that alternative terms for linear variety include an affine subspace, but he uses linear variety throughout, where linear variety $V = x_0 + M$ where $M$ is a subspace. Like the original poster, I'm having trouble. My main question comes down to whether vectors in some vector space $X$ must begin at the origin of $X$. Given any $S \subset X$, must each $S$ begin at $\theta_X$, the origin of $X$? If so, how would any affine space $V$ in $X$ contain the elements, if containing them "requires" that they begin at $\theta_V$?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120476/basis-of-an-affine-subspace) thread may help.

Comment: @lithium123 Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: @akm Are you still having trouble with this?